# Почему игнорируется "/" при указании пути к файлу в Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel

Просто хочу вставить картинку в авторизации Laravel и подставляю такой путь в img:

```php
<img src="{{ asset('storage/images/') . Auth::user()->avatar }}"
```

Но в итоге последний `"/"` игнорируется и получается это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл естественно не отображается по такому пути.

В то же время если я пишу так:

```php
<img src="{{ asset('storage/images/') . '/' . Auth::user()->avatar }}"
```

После обновления `"/"` появляется там где нужно и изображение появляется:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В примере в видео, по которому пишу код у автора все работает как в первом варианте и ему не приходится дополнительно конкатенировать ещё один слэш.

**Почему у меня так происходит?**

**UPD/**
На 2-м изображении стрелку не на тот слэш поставил
Имеется в виду последний слэш - между `images` и `auto.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно потому что хелпер `asset()` генерирует [путь к файлу](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-asset) естественно что в конце пути к файлу не может быть слеша, Вы же пытаетесь при помощи этого хелпера указать путь к директории, что наверное не есть правильным. Вы можете прописывать путь к аватару таким образом:

```
{{ asset('storage/images/' . Auth::user()->avatar) }}
```

**UPD:** Также если посмотреть в код самого хелпера, и проследовать к классу `UrlGenerator.php` можем увидеть что слеш убирается при помощи `trim()`:

```
    return $this->removeIndex($root).'/'.trim($path, '/');
```

Comment: Да! Вот блин, из-за невнимательности вынес конкатенацию **за** скобку.   
Отмотал назад, у автора видео как раз также, как и вы написали.
Спасибо!